# Drop down integration with bubble chart

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular9, angular10

I am using bubble chart in my application. Code is as follows:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bubblechart

```
<h1 style="text-align:center">Polar Chart in Angular</h1>
<div id="container"></div>



import { Component, VERSION ,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

declare var require: any;
const More = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
More(Highcharts);

const Exporting = require('highcharts/modules/exporting');
Exporting(Highcharts);

const ExportData = require('highcharts/modules/export-data');
ExportData(Highcharts);

const Accessibility = require('highcharts/modules/accessibility');
Accessibility(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{

   public options: any = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sugar and fat intake per country'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.name}, fat: {point.x}g, sugar: {point.y}g, obesity: {point.z}%.'
        }
    },
   xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Daily fat intake'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} gr'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 65,
            label: {
                rotation: 0,
                y: 15,
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic'
                },
                text: 'Safe fat intake 65g/day'
            },
            zIndex: 3
        }],
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: 60 to 100 grams.'
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Daily sugar intake'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} gr'
        },
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            width: 2,
            value: 50,
            label: {
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic'
                },
                text: 'Safe sugar intake 50g/day',
                x: -10
            },
            zIndex: 3
        }],
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: 0 to 160 grams.'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.country}</h3></th></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Fat intake:</th><td>{point.x}g</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Sugar intake:</th><td>{point.y}g</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Obesity (adults):</th><td>{point.z}%</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        followPointer: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            { x: 95, y: 95, z: 13.8, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium' },
            { x: 86.5, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany' },
            { x: 80.8, y: 91.5, z: 15.8, name: 'FI', country: 'Finland' },
            { x: 80.4, y: 102.5, z: 12, name: 'NL', country: 'Netherlands' },
            { x: 80.3, y: 86.1, z: 11.8, name: 'SE', country: 'Sweden' },
            { x: 78.4, y: 70.1, z: 16.6, name: 'ES', country: 'Spain' },
            { x: 74.2, y: 68.5, z: 14.5, name: 'FR', country: 'France' },
            { x: 73.5, y: 83.1, z: 10, name: 'NO', country: 'Norway' },
            { x: 71, y: 93.2, z: 24.7, name: 'UK', country: 'United Kingdom' },
            { x: 69.2, y: 57.6, z: 10.4, name: 'IT', country: 'Italy' },
            { x: 68.6, y: 20, z: 16, name: 'RU', country: 'Russia' },
            { x: 65.5, y: 126.4, z: 35.3, name: 'US', country: 'United States' },
            { x: 65.4, y: 50.8, z: 28.5, name: 'HU', country: 'Hungary' },
            { x: 63.4, y: 51.8, z: 15.4, name: 'PT', country: 'Portugal' },
            { x: 64, y: 82.9, z: 31.3, name: 'NZ', country: 'New Zealand' }
        ]
    }]

  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){
    Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);
  }
}
```

I want to have two dropdown's at top of the screen, so that if user select any value from dropdown, bubble chart change accordingly. I tried finding it everywhere but didn;t got any example on how to implement it. Data shown in drop down will be in form of array in ts file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. Please check this out
Script for dropdown and graph

```
 var data = [
    ['data4', 'data2', 'data3'],
    [90, 120, 300],
    [40, 160, 240],
    [50, 200, 290],
    [120, 160, 230],
    [80, 130, 300],
    [90, 220, 320]
];
$(function () {
   
    // Initial chart
    var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            rows: data,
            type: 'bar'
        }
    });
    
    // Redraw chart depending on which option is selected
    $("#chartType").change(function (evt) {
        var chartSelection = $("#chartType").val();
        var chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                rows: data,
                type: chartSelection
            }
        });
    });
    
});
```

In html

```
<select id="chartType">
    <option value="bar">bar chart</option>
    <option value="area">area chart</option>
    <option value="line">line chart</option>
    <option value="spline">spline chart</option>
</select>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/km97cdL3/

Comment: nops this code isn not working in fiddle itself

Comment: What I get from your question you want to update the graph by selecting the value from the dropdown. Am I right??

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a base demo where you can see how to `update` the chart depends on the value set in the select. You should be able to reproduce it for your needs.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1pzxt79a/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update